# QML: How to delete an objects created with Qt.createQmlObject?

Tags: qt, qml

I have some objects created in QML code with

```
Qt.createQmlObject (...)
```

How can I delete/remove these objects?

Answer (score 7):

```
something = Qt.createQmlObject (...);
something.destroy();
```

Comment: What if I have many objects, and want to show them all, and next delete all? How to store the 'references' to these objects?

Comment: You need to create java script file (.js) and declare an array for your objects there. So you could include this file in your qml files and use this array.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this article:
[Dynamic Object Management in QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html)
and on this part especially:

> Note that it is safe to call destroy() on an object within that
>   object. Objects are not destroyed the instant destroy() is called, but
>   are cleaned up sometime between the end of that script block and the
>   next frame (unless you specified a non-zero delay).