# Qt5 - QML: How to dynamically erase objects using a Button

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

Below the lay-out of a minimal example I prepared. This is the print screen of the interface after performing all necessary operations, also in case needed the source code can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/textchange/src/master/):

[image]

At this point I would like to erase the objects using the `Button` "Clear List" I don't need anymore but I obtained only a partial result as is possible to see below:

[image: partial]

**the expected** result would be to erase all the objects and the `Button` "Clear List" itself. The final lay-out after clicking the button should look like below:

[image: initial]

The code I am using for the minimal example is below, you can copy/paste on your computer and it will work as it is:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls.impl 2.12  // for IconLabel

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    function buttonClick(button)
    {
        button.text = qsTr(" YES Connecting");
        button.enabled = false;
        if (button.background && button.background instanceof Rectangle) {
            button.background.color = "green";
            button.background.gradient = null;
            button.background.visible = true;
        }
        if (button.contentItem && button.contentItem instanceof IconLabel) {
            button.contentItem.color = "white";
            button.contentItem.font.bold = true;
            button.contentItem.font.pointSize = 20;
        }
    }

    function buttonClearListOfObjects(buttonClear)
    {
        buttonClear.text = qsTr("Clear List");
        buttonClear.enabled = false;
        if (buttonClear.background && buttonClear.background instanceof Rectangle) {
            buttonClear.background.color = "red";
            buttonClear.background.gradient = null;
            buttonClear.background.visible = true;
        }
        if (buttonClear.contentItem && buttonClear.contentItem instanceof IconLabel) {
            buttonClear.contentItem.color = "white";
            buttonClear.contentItem.font.bold = true;
            buttonClear.contentItem.font.pointSize = 20;
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        Button {
            id: dialogA
            text: pBar.running ? "Connecting..." : "Not - Connected"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            font.pointSize: 20
            spacing: 10
            onClicked: {
                buttonClick(this)
                //pBar.startComputation()
            }
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            id: layout
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            spacing: 10
            GroupBox {
                id: box1
                width: parent.width
                title: "Connection"
                font.pointSize: 20
                Layout.fillWidth: parent
                spacing: 10

                GridLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    columns: 1
                    RowLayout {
                        id: row1
                        spacing: 200
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Label {
                            id: textField
                            text: "Connection:"
                            font.pointSize: 15
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                        }
                        Text {
                            id: connected
                            text: qsTr("Not-Connected")
                            color: "red"
                            font.pointSize: 15
                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            states: [
                                State {
                                    name: "connecting"
                                    //when: pBar.running
                                    PropertyChanges {
                                        target: connected
                                        text: qsTr("Connecting...")
                                        color: "blue"
                                        font.bold: true
                                    }
                                },
                                State {
                                    name: "connected"
                                    //when: !pBar.running && pBar.finished //   something.connected
                                    PropertyChanges {
                                        target: connected
                                        text: qsTr("Yes! Connected...")
                                        color: "green"
                                        font.bold: true
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            GroupBox {
                id: boxprogress
                title: "Connection Progress"
                font.pointSize: 20
                Layout.fillWidth: parent
                width: parent.width
                spacing: 10
                GridLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    columns: 1
                    RowLayout {
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        ProgressBar {
                            id: progressbar_id
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            Layout.fillHeight: true
                            width: parent.width
                            from: 0
                            to: 40
                            value: pBar.progress
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Button {
            id: clist
            text: "Clear List"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            font.pointSize: 20
            width: parent.width
            enabled: true
            onClicked: {
                buttonClearListOfObjects(this)
//                 var i = dialogA.children.length;
//                 dialogA.children[i-1].destroy()

                 var j = layout.children.length;
                 layout.children[j-1].destroy()

//                 var k = box1.children.length;
//                 box1.children[k].destroy()

//                 var l = row1.children.length;
//                 row1.children[l-1].destroy()

//                var ii = textField.children.length;
//                textField.children[ii].destroy()

                var jj = connected.children.length;
                connected.children[jj-1].destroy()

                var kk = boxprogress.children.length;
                boxprogress.children[kk-1].destroy()

                var kkk = clist.children.length;
                clist.children[kk-1].destroy()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**What I tried so far**:

**1)** After doing a lot of research I came across the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025962/qml-how-to-delete-an-objects-created-with-qt-createqmlobject) which was useful in order to understand how to actually erase objects dynamically. But to be specific in my example I didn't use `Qt.createQmlObject (...)` because I am not familiar enough with this one.

**2)** After that I went ahead and looked for any additional possible source to help me move forward and I found [this post](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/68689-Properly-destroy-a-qml-dynamic-object-derived-from-another-item) which was useful too but didn't carry specific information I was looking for.

I understand from the same post that erasing objects it is a matter of eliminating the last one that was added and that explains the decreasing count on the loop. however after executing a similar procedure I was only able to erase a piece of the example.

**3)** I obtain so far from the compiler the following error if that could be useful `TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined`
Which I think is related to how I destroy the children.

**4)** [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902936/how-to-delete-qml-object) is the closest I found and in fact I implemented part of it.

**5)** Very interesting is [this post too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802547/how-to-create-destroy-dynamic-objects-after-the-same-event-in-qml) but still the problem remains.

In my case I tried to go ahead and chose the destroy function in the documentation that is erasing the children, but I am not sure of its benefits. I am saying this because, despite I implemented the solution, I was only able to partially erase dynamically the objects

What am I missing from achieving the lay-out I showed above? 
Thank you for pointing in the right direct

Comment: Do you really need to destroy them or is making them `visible: false` enough?

Comment: I think that using the invisible property could be enough. However, the goal would be that if I click again on the `Button` Not-Connected, I should see again all the controls on the first print screen I posted. Would invisible make this result?

Comment: Also, thank you very much for taking the time to read the question Amfasis :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not destroy objects which are not created dynamically.

About the `TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined`, it is happening because of `connected` object has no children thus the `jj` is 0 and `connected.children[-1]` is `undefined`.

IMHO, you should get familiar with `Qt.createQmlObject(...)` and other similar methods, if you want to create dynamic templates. You could also make those controls invisible if you are not running your application in a resource-constrained embedded device.

To make the desired components invisible, you will have three major options.

- Bind `visible` to condition(s) which should make those components invisible which can get quite complicated and less maintainable.
- Set `visible` property of those objects through your functions which may break previous possible bindings.
- Do the whole job through `states` property of a relevant parent and add property changes in those `states` and simply change the state name in your function.

You will find quite a lot of examples of these three options. But to keep yourself in the proper track, I highly recommend you take the ***states*** path.

Here is an example copied from [State](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html) Qml type docs.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: myRect
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "black"

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: myRect.state == 'clicked' ? myRect.state = "" : myRect.state = 'clicked';
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "clicked"
            PropertyChanges { target: myRect; color: "red" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question. Making the objects invisible could be the answer. How should I modify the code? Could you please provide some explanation? :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! :)